# why thymeleaf templates doesnt work in mobile? [SOLVED]

Tags: spring-boot, mobile, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf, responsive

I was developing a raw application in spring boot with thymeleaf and I can not make it work on mobiles, the page uses bootstrap and collapses perfectly when I lower the browser window, but on mobile devices, it scales to the full resolution possible, as if like desktop resolution where...

this is mi image of my app in mobile:

[in mobile mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5l6C.png)

this is my image when i try when collapse the window od navigator in responsive mode:

[responsive mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWYr2.png)

the code of my application is here: https://github.com/Daviddg91/APIUsuariosSpringBoot

thanks and good code, Regards

-----------------Edit:---------------

I have been testing the spring-mobile-device library but it only allows you to change the page according to the type of device, it does not allow you to autoconfigure the responsive of the page and integrate with the thymeleaf template

SOLVED: this meta tags in layout file was working responsive:

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: You are welcome to answer your own questions by posting answers (instead of adding an answer into the question). People will see that the question has an answer - and even has an *accepted* answer. That way, you don't need to add "[SOLVED]" to the question title, either. Have you taken [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Comment: Thank you for your post, helped me with the same problem.
Basicaly, you just need to add this meta-tag:

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">